# Are there any results similar to the Paley–Zygmund inequality, but for probability density functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, approximation

For a random variable $X$, the Paley-Zygmund inequality is given by

$$P(X>\theta \text{ E}[X])\geq\frac{(1-\theta)^2\text{ E}[X]^2}{\text{Var}{X}+\text{ E}[X]^2}.$$

This may be strengthened by the Cauchy–Schwartz inequality such that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(X>\theta\text{ E}[X])&\geq\frac{(1-\theta)^{2}\text{ E}[X]^{2}}{\text{Var}X+(1-\theta)^{2}\text{ E}[X]^{2}}\\P(X<x)&\leq1-\frac{\left(1-\frac{x}{\text{E}[X]}\right){}^{2}\text{ E}[X]^{2}}{\text{Var}X+\left(1-\frac{x}{\text{E}[X]}\right) \text{E}[X]^{2}}
\end{split}\end{equation}

It would be nice to differentiate the third equation and produce a probability density function $f_X(x)$, but inequalities do not hold under differentiation.

So, are there any sharp inequalities, similar in nature to the Paley-Zygmund inequality, but for probability density functions instead of cumulative distributions? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There will not be general inequalities for densities, as these can vary locally without having much impact on the moments of the distribution.  I would guess you might be able to put an upper bound on the minimum density in some interval or perhaps a lower bound on the maximum density, but I doubt these would be of much use.